# Integral in commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Let's assume I have an expression like,

$$
\left[\int\! \mathrm dt ~\hat{H}_1(t),\int \! \mathrm dt^{\prime}~\hat{H}_2(t^{\prime})\right].
$$

When would I be allowed to write the integrals in front of the commutator, when not?

Comment: I am a bit lost, unsurprisingly :). Do you mean to integrate first ( I presume you don't) and would it work with summations?  And should it be on mathSE...  and where did this horror arrive from in the first place:). Is it in a textbook?

Comment: Show some effort to work it out yourself! For instance, think about whether you could do this if it were finite sums, not integrals.

Comment: First, thank you! And sorry for the unclear question. I'm thinking of rewriting it to $ \int \int [H_1(t),H_2(t)]$. Do you have a clear argument why this would not be allowed?

Comment: Thank you too. It's clear that I would not be allowed in general with sums. But I would like to have a clear mathematical argumentation for that :-)

Comment: @CountTo10  v(2)?    What's that?

Comment: @garyp sorry for not being clearer Gary,  I thought the convention was when  the  first equation ( or question or answer) was left as is, and then modified in the comments, you could use this shorthand. The integrals were inside, now the OP has pulled them outside. I will modify the comment, my apologies. V as in version. I will be more precise in future.

Comment: VTC as a mathSE question.

Comment: If every $A (a) $ is everywhere defined, bounded, the map $a \to A (a) $ is weakly continuous, and locally there is a $a$-uniform bound for the norms  of these operators, the definition of $R =\int_X A (a) da$ is the unique operator such that $<u| R v> = \int_X <u|A(a)v> da $ for every $u,v $. Using this def recursively, you see that you,in fact,  can deal with integration symbols as you suspect. Weakening the hypotheses, the proofs are more difficult but the result can be achieved similarly...

Comment: Sorry, you are using the same variable $t $ in both operators. No, it does not work this way. It works if the two integrals are referred to different variables $t_1$ and $t_2$...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this but it is to long for a comment, so please give some feedback on this answer.
First, assuming those integrals converge, let me define:

\begin{align}
\int\! \mathrm dt ~\hat{H}_1(t)&\equiv \hat{I}_1,\\\\
\int\! \mathrm dt ~\hat{H}_2(t)&\equiv \hat{I}_2.
\end{align}

With that we can rewrite the commutator as:

\begin{align}
\left[\int\! \mathrm dt ~\hat{H}_1(t),\int \! \mathrm dt^{\prime}~\hat{H}_2(t^{\prime})\right]
&=\hat{I}_1\int \! \mathrm dt^{\prime}~\hat{H}_2(t^{\prime})-\hat{I}_2\int \! \mathrm dt~\hat{H}_1(t)\\\\
&=\int \! \mathrm dt^{\prime}\hat{I}_1~\hat{H}_2(t^{\prime})-\int \! \mathrm dt~\hat{I}_2\hat{H}_1(t).
\end{align}
If I understand the integral as basically a Riemann sum, then the Integral is linear. If I multiply a sum of operators by an operator it is the same as the sum over all summands multiplied by the operator. Note I did not commute any operators.

If one puts the defintions of $\hat{I}_1$ and $\hat{I}_2$ back in we get:
\begin{align}
\int \! \mathrm dt^{\prime}\hat{I}_1~\hat{H}_2(t^{\prime})-\int \! \mathrm dt~\hat{I}_2\hat{H}_1(t)&=\int\int\mathrm dt'~\mathrm dt ~\hat{H}_1(t)\hat{H}_2(t')-\int\int  \!\mathrm dt~\mathrm dt' ~\hat{H}_2(t')\hat{H}_1(t)\\\\&=\int\int\mathrm dt~\mathrm dt' ~\hat{H}_1(t)\hat{H}_2(t')-\int\int  \!\mathrm dt~\mathrm dt' ~\hat{H}_2(t')\hat{H}_1(t)\\\\
&=\int\int  \!\mathrm dt~\mathrm dt'\left[\hat{H}_1(t),\hat{H}_2(t')\right].
\end{align}
Where we changed the order of integration (swapped the differentials) in the first term. If one understands the integral as a Riemann sum and especially if the integration domains are equal this should be valid.

I edited this post: in my first version I only relabeled $t$ and $t'$ which resulted in a different expression not the commutator. But even looking at that expression under the integral would be equal to the commutator. I think picking out the integrand and looking at it isolated was not right.

Comment: Why don't you use $dt \, dt' = dt'\. dt $, instead of relabeling the variables in the first integral? You might reach a softer conclusion :)

Comment: That is what I meant with "order of integration". I was not too sure about that point. I mean for most ordinary integrals the order does not realy matter but I lack any detailed knowlege of integrals over plain operators. If one can just swap those differentials then everything is fine and one would get the double integral over the commutator.

Comment: Thinking about that point more I think it should be no problem swapping those differentials especially if one assumes the integration domains to be identical. I will edit the answer.